Degree of an elliptic function
I'm attending a course about elliptic functions (over complex)
The professor defined the degree of an elliptic function as the number of poles (counted with multiplicity) in the fundamental domain (the torus).
He also has gave us as exercise to proove that if f is elliptic $deg(f)=[\mathbb{C}(x,y):\mathbb{C}(f)]$ where $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ is the field of rational function over the elliptic curve (s.t $y^2=4x^3-g_2x-g_3$ is the elliptic function defined by the lattice that defines the periods).
I'm stuck with that, can't even start
